# Toggle (show or hide) visibility of content type field in view depending on relationship with other content type

Tags: nodes, javascript, hooks, caching

I have a member content type that displays info about a company's member. One of the fields is named **member publications**, and it's a link to a blog view where the publications of the member (another content type) are displayed.

I want to show or hide the **member publications** field depending if the member has any publications.

I tried this using the **hook_page_attachments** using this snippet

```
function MYMODULE_page_attachments(array &$page) {
  //This line works the first time i open the node page, but not after is cached
  $entity = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');

  if( $entity !== null && $entity->bundle() == 'member'){
    
    $publications = Drupal::entityQuery('node')
      ->condition('type','publication')->condition('field_publication_author',$entity->id(),'IN')->execute();

    $numberOfPublications = sizeof($publications);

    if($numberOfPublications !== null){
      $page['#attached']['drupalSettings']['MYMODULE'] = [
        'memberPublications' => $numberOfPublications
      ];
    }
  }
}
```

And then i just show the field or not in js depending on the value attached

```
let memberPublications = settings.MYMODULE.memberPublications;

        if(memberPublications == 0){
          $('.field--name-field-member-publications').css('display','none');
        }
```

This works fine the first time i open the member node page, but when i remove all the members publications, the button still shows, the page gets cached and the value doesn't change, when i remove all cache if works again.

Is there a way to have a dynamic field inside a node, that appears or dissapears based in a condition that involves a relationship with another content type? And can it be done without having to reload the cache every time for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hook you are using is only for global attachments. If you have an attachment specific to nodes attach it to nodes:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter() for node entities.
 */
function mymodule_node_view_alter(array &$build, EntityInterface $node, EntityViewDisplayInterface $display) {
  if ($build['#view_mode'] == 'full' && $node->bundle() == 'member') {
    ...
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['MYMODULE'] = [
      'memberPublications' => $numberOfPublications,
    ];
    // add list tag for the content type publication
    $build['#cache']['tags'][] = 'node_list:publication';
  }
}
```

This solves most caching issues because nodes are already setup to be cached properly. In this case you need to add a cache tag for the other content type, though, to recalculate the entity query in case a publication is added or deleted.

There are of course other solutions without javascript, but this would be a too broad for an answer. So I'm focusing on why the solution you've found so far doesn't work.

Comment: Danke schön! Do you know where to find other resources to learn more about other solutions to achieve the same result?

Comment: Now that you are in this entity view alter hook you could try to hide the field in PHP.